# My switch (view.getId()) doesnt work

Tags: android, button, switch-statement, android-imageview, android-button

I'm trying to work on an exercise, which means i need to change an image from an imageView with a button. The whole thing is implemented into another project of the exercise.

The problem is: it doesn't even open the Toast "test" in the second case.

```
package de.vogella.android.temperature;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
  private EditText text;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tempbutton);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageconverter);
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.tempbutton:
                    button1Click();
                    break;

                case R.id.imageconverter:

                    button2Click();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button2.setOnClickListener(listener);

  }




  public void button1Click (){
      RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
        }

        float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
        if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
        text.setText(String.valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
        celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
        fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
        } else {
        text.setText(String
        .valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
        fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
        celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
        }
  }

  public void button2Click (){
      ImageView frontImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myicon);
        frontImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.assigned);
        Toast.makeText(this,"done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  }
```

XML File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/myColor"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/celsius" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fahrenheit" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tempbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:text="@string/calc"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/author"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <DigitalClock
        android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:text="DigitalClock" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageconverter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Change Image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:src="@drawable/initial" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at de.vogella.android.temperature.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:24)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
02-25 16:03:00.228: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Where do you set the `Listener` for the `Button`s?

Comment: Please post the layout XML, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cooked it wrong. You should find your button and then attach listener:

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tempbutton);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageconverter);
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.tempbutton:
                button1Click();
                break;

            case R.id.imageconverter:
                Toast.makeText(this, "test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                button2Click();
                break;
        }
    }
};
button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thanks :) But when i add the line: button1.setOnClickListener(listener); it shows "Syntax error on token "listener", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token"

Comment: did you copy this inside `onCreate` method of your activity?

Comment: outside, just before my other methods

Comment: no error anymore, but when i run it: "Unfortunately, Temperature Converter has stopped.

Comment: did in my original post

Comment: nope, you can filter out only the messages related with your app

Comment: so please make sure that you have `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` at the beginning of your `onCreate` method and that ids inside `findViewById` correspond to ids in XML respecting the case

Comment: what about the Button initializations and the creation ofo OnClickListener? at the moment they are outside the onCreate and outside the onClick, right?

Comment: no, all my code should be inside onCreate, just paste it there

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to do  it like this then your Activity needs to implement `View.OnClickListener`.

Next, you need to set the click listener for the button, likely in `onCreate`.  For example, `<yourButton>.setOnClickListener(this)`.

Comment: you can also set `onClick` attribute in the layout xml

Comment: if you use `onClick` you also have view as the parameter, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick " if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity)."

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing it in the layout xml, you are not setting your click listener. You need to implement `View.OnClickListener` and call `setOnClickListener` on each button.

Answer (score 0):

I think your "test" toast isn't visible because right after you show it, you show another toast, the "done" one. The last one gets visible, right?

Oh, and you're missing the `android:onClick="onClick"` in your xml, for your `imageconverter` button.